# Getting exception near DefaultHttpClient when i am trying to access restful wcf service in java.Here is my code

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, rest

Getting exception near DefaultHttpClient when i am trying to access restful wcf service in java.Here is my code:

```
public String rest(String SERVICE_URI){
    String a="";

    try{

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(SERVICE_URI + "/hello");
    request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");



    **DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();**

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

    HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

    // Read response data into buffer
    char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
    InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
    reader.read(buffer);
    stream.close();

    JSONArray plates = new JSONArray(new String(buffer));
    a=plates.toString();
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
     }


    return a;
}
```

the exception is :

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class:
> ```
>
> org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient,
>   method: createHttpParams signature:
>   ()Lorg/apache/http/params/HttpParams;)
>   Incompatible argument to function

Please can anyone help me ...Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a class loader problem. Your code is probably compiled against one jar file (containing the HTTP client stuff). But when it's run, a different, incompatible jar file with the same class is used.

Are you running the code within an application server? If yes, the application server might already have a different version of the Apache Http client libraries in a shared location that takes precedence.

Answer (score -1):

I would guess that your problem might be related to the fact that you are setting a Content-Type header for a GET.  GET requests should not include Content-Type headers.